# Submit bug report for util-linux

Tags: bugs, util-linux

How / where do I submit a bug report for `util-linux`?

Specifically I want to submit a bug for `losetup` which exits `0` but doesn't actually remove a device under some cirsumstances with  the `-d` flag.

Comment: There is no `-D` option in losetup.  You mean `-d`?

Comment: `losetup` has had a `-D` option [for almost six years now](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/commit/34f9b684c0b77030b8d318b5949b60e790d1b654).  However, one does not pass parameters to it.

Comment: Updated question and posted as issue [here](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/issues/484).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the trail (starting with CentOS) of

 `"rpm -qi util-linux" ->
 "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Util-linux" ->
 "https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux" ->
 README`

which says:

BUG REPORTING:

```
  E-MAIL: util-linux@vger.kernel.org
  Web:    https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/issues

  This project has no resources to provide support for distribution specific
  issues. For end users it is recommended to utilize the distribution's
  support system.
```

If you believe the issue is generic to all util-linux installs (and can demonstrate it with a copy compiled from github) then send to the list.  Otherwise you should contact the support address for the distribution you're using (eg https://www.debian.org/Bugs/Reporting on Debian).

Comment: Thanks! I raised it as a GitHub issue [here](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/issues/484).